# AngularJS form post using controllers and services

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```js
jc.controller.js

  angular.module('sd').controller('CJController', [
    '$scope', 'jcreate', function($scope, $http, jcreate) {
      return jcreate.sendJob(jobItems)(function() {
        return {
          create: jobItems
        };
      });
    }
  ]);


jc.services.js

  angular.module('sd').service('jcreate', [
    "$scope", "$http", function($scope, $http) {

      _cjObj = [];
      _cjObj = $.param({
        json: JSON.stringify(
          description = $scope.name, 
        )
      });
      _create = function() {
        return $http.post('URLtoBeAdded', _cjObj).success(function(response, status, headers, config) {
          return alert(1);
        }).error(function(response, status, headers, config) {
          return alert(2);
        });
      };
      return {
        create: function(jobItems) {
          return _create();
        }
      };
    }
  ]);
```

```html
HTML

<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" ng-submit="sendJob(jobItems)" ng-controller="CJController">
        <div id="jobConnectionTab">
            <div class="field-canvas">
                <p class="group-lable">Connection</p>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="description">Name:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <input type="name" class="form-control" id="description" placeholder="Enter description" ng-model="jobItems.name">
                    </div>
                </div>

<div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning" value="Clean"></button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit"></button>
                </div>
            </div>
</form>
```

I have small application using Angular JS and I have splited to three pages as follows

- Form page - HTML
- controller - JS
- services - JS

On page loading following error is given.

Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- jcreate

After update the problem according to given instruction, following error pop:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- jcreate

Answer (score 1):

You are missing $http in array:-

It should be like:

```
 angular.module('sd').controller('CJController', [
    '$scope','$http', 'jcreate', function($scope, $http, jcreate) {
..

}
```

Second you cannot use $scope inside the service of angular js. Just remove it and use alternative.